# Cast Nested List<X> to Nested List<Y>

Tags: c#, list, casting, nested, nested-lists

I know its possible to cast a list of items from one type to another but how do you cast a nested list  to nested List .

Already tried solutions:

```
List<List<String>> new_list = new List<List<string>>(abc.Cast<List<String>>());
```

and

```
List<List<String>> new_list = abc.Cast<List<String>>().ToList();
```

Both of which give the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'.

Comment: You can't cast `int` to `string` anyway so even if you did not have nested lists it still would not work.

Comment: if your purpose is only about to change the type of the generic element, you can create a generic extension method with a return value of T.ToString()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Select()` instead of that way:

```
List<List<String>> new_list = abc.Select(x => x.Select(y=> y.ToString()).ToList()).ToList();
```

***The reason of this exception:*** `Cast` will throw `InvalidCastException`, because it  tries to convert `List<int>` to `object`, then cast it to `List<string>`:

```
List<int> myListInt = new List<int> { 5,4};
object myObject = myListInt;
List<string> myListString = (List<string>)myObject; // Exception will be thrown here
```

So, this is not possible. Even, you can't cast `int` to `string` also.

```
int myInt = 11;
object myObject = myInt;
string myString = (string)myObject; // Exception will be thrown here
```

The reason of this exception is, a ***boxed value*** can only be unboxed to a variable of the ***exact same type***.

***Additional Information:***

Here is the implemetation of the [`Cast<TResult>(this IEnumerable source)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,27bb217a6d5457ec) method, if you interested:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Cast<TResult>(this IEnumerable source) {
    IEnumerable<TResult> typedSource = source as IEnumerable<TResult>;
    if (typedSource != null) return typedSource;
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    return CastIterator<TResult>(source);
}
```

As you see, it returns `CastIterator`:

```
static IEnumerable<TResult> CastIterator<TResult>(IEnumerable source) {
    foreach (object obj in source) yield return (TResult)obj;
}
```

Look at the above code. It will iterate over source with `foreach` loop, and converts all items to `object`, then to `(TResult)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation/information. Much appreciated.