# Casting List of nested type in C#

Tags: c#, list, casting

I've checked some answers about casting lists in C# here on SO.

If I'm not mistaken, in [Cast Nested List<X> to Nested List<Y>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28642650/cast-nested-listx-to-nested-listy) the ToString() makes new instance of string.

Consider classes:

```
public class abstract A {...}

public class B : A {...}

public class DataEntry<T, K> : Tuple<T, K> where K : A {...}
```

next consider list of data entries:

```
List<DataEntry<float[], B>> myList = ...
```

how do I overcast it to:

```
List<DataEntry<float[], A>> myList2 = ???
```

without making new DataEntry instances? The List.Cast doesn't work. Also casting elements of list one by one

```
foreach(entry : dataEntryList) {
    myNewList.Add((DataEntry<float[], A>) entry);
}
```

I need to cast all elements without making new instances. Is it possible, please?

EDIT: 
K:B -> K:A

Comment: The definition of `DataEntry` requires `K` to be/inherit `B` - it can't be `A`!

Comment: As @Amit said. you will not be able to cast this because of `where K : B`

Comment: sorry, mistake, It should have been A.

Comment: The .Cast() works flawless with your update. `myList.Cast<List<DataEntry<float[], A>>>();` -> No errors

Comment: no, that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use the `.Cast<OtherType>()` extension method in namespace `System.Linq` as mentioned by @lokusking.

You cannot cast the entire type as the types involved are not co-variant - their type parameters are not declared with the `out` keyword.